# How to call a function that targets every worksheet except the first one in VBA

Tags: vba, call, worksheet

I'm new to VBA and was stuck on something.
I've basically got 4 different worksheets in an Excel File and the first one is basically empty except for a button which I want to link to a macro that calls a function that targets every other worksheet EXCEPT the first one (the one that has the button on it) so I was wondering how I would do this.

So far I have this but it doesn't seem to be working. In the function that I call I also want to only target every worksheet except the first one and then have a long list of things that I want to impact the three worksheets so would I have to repeat the same code? What code would I need in both the Function Calling thing and also in the function titled ProcessData to be able to target all but the first worksheet with a long list of things that transform the data on those sheets?

```
Sub DumpOutput()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name <> "Main" Then
        ProcessData WS
    End If
Next WS
End Sub

Sub ProcessData(ByRef w As Worksheet)
With w
    Range("f1:f3") = Application.Transpose(Array("1", "2", "3"))
    Debug.Print .Name
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`

Comment: Are you assuming that the first worksheet is called "Main"?

Comment: I called the first worksheet "Main" Pat and omegastripes - where would I add that code in? Would I remove For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name <> "Main" Then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to want to pass over each worksheet object into the processing sub procedure.

```
Sub FunctionCaller()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Main" Then
            ProcessData ws
        End If
    Next WS
End Sub

sub ProcessData(byref w as worksheet)
    with w
        'process the worksheet here.
        'any worksheet object members (e.g. Range, Cells, Name, etc) need to
        'be prefixed with a period (.) to be associated with the parent
        'worksheet defined in the With ... End With and passed into the
        'procedure as the parameter (e.g. .Range, .Cells, .Name, etc) 
        .Range("f1:f3") = Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3))
        debug.print .name
    end with
end sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I was wondering what the ws after the ProcessData is for and also what does the byref w as worksheet do?

Comment: Sorry to jump in @Jeeped, but I wanted to encourage @nathan to go down this path for his solution. The `WS` is declared at the top as a `Worksheet`. Therefore, you're "passing" each worksheet selected by `For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` to the procedure `ProcessData` one at a time. Likewise, the parameter `w` in the `ProcessData` procedure receives the Worksheet, and `ByRef` means the thing that is passed to `w` can be changed (vs. `ByVal`, which means it cannot be changed). The default is `ByRef`, but it doesn't hurt to specify `ByRef` explicitly, especially if you'll be changing it.

Comment: Hi Glenn, Thanks for the information. I've edited the code above and just put in a simple function to try and add a sixth column to data 1, data 2 and data 3 but it doesn't seem to do anything. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: Oh actually I just saw that it's only impacting the first page with the button still @GlennFromIowa. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: You need to prefix worksheet object members like range or cells with a period (e.g. `.` ). This associates each .range or .cells object with the parent worksheet defined in the `with w ... end with` statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub FunctionCaller()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name Then
            Call ProcessData
        End If
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would I need to add in the code into the ProcessData function too?

Comment: Yes so you can do what you need with that Worksheet, Call ProcessData(WS) That is why the other person added the byref W as Worksheet